# Deploy Gadle built Ear using eclipse on wilfdfly

Tags: eclipse, gradle, wildfly

I’m trying to deploy the Ear file which contains the META-INF folder and had a dependency on the war file but some how I’m not able to add the META-INF folder in the ear file. I tried keeping the META-INF folder in the application folder(src/main/application/META-INF/) but then while publishing ear from eclipse it’s throwing a null pointer exception.
Gradle : 7.5
Wildfly: 8
Below I’m pasted my build.gradle file.
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
buildscript {
    ext.repos = {
        maven {
            url “${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/${PROXY_REPO_KEY}”
            credentials {
                username = “${ARTIFACTORY_USER}”
                password = “${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}”
            }
        }
    }
    repositories repos
}

plugins {
    id ‘java’
    id ‘maven-publish’
    id ‘eclipse-wtp’
    id ‘idea’
    id ‘ear’
}

group = ‘com.one’
description = ‘Dragon6’
version = ‘xyz’

repositories repos

configurations{
    earlib
}

dependencies {
    earlib project(‘:Dao’)
    earlib ‘javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1’
    deploy project(path: “:Dragon6Web”, configuration: “archives”)

}

tasks.withType(Ear) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

ear{
    archiveName = ‘Dragon6.ear’
}

// Define the EAR configuration

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = ‘UTF-8’
}
```

I'm expecting either my jboss-deployment-structure.xml which is in META-INF is published to eclipse or if it's there anything I can do with build.gradle which is being done in jboss-deployment-structure.xml is works for me